# Require is not defined after installed nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

First I dowloaded nodejs from [link](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Then I installed browserify `npm install -g browserify`

Then I installed fs `npm install fs`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test", "Hey there!", function(err) {
    if(err) {return console.log(err);}
    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at index.html:12:12
```

Why require is still not defined? What could I do to get the code to be executable?

Comment: Not only is require not defined in the browser environment, Node's library (including fs) isn't either.

Answer (score 2):

Node.js is a stand-alone environment for running JavaScript. It is not a browser extension.

To run Node.js code, save it in a file with a `.js` file extension, then run it with:

```
node yourFile.js
```

If you want Node.js code and browser code to interact then the typical way is to write a server in Node.js that hosts a web service. Express.js is a popular way to do this. You can then use Ajax to make HTTP requests to that web service.

For bi-directional communication (as opposed to the request/response of Ajax) look at Socket.io.

---

> I just want it to be local storage, so I do not want to share the datas between the users, I just want to interact with there own local storage datas.

If you want to use the [localStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) provided by browsers, then do so.

`localStorage` doesn't need Node.js. It doesn't need the `fs` module that is built into Node.js. It doesn't need the `require` method that is part of the CommonJS module specification.

You can't muck around freely on the user's file system from code running in the browser. That would be a huge security problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use node APIs in browser environment; more specifically browser won't allow script to directly interact with file APIs like Node.

Either run your code in node as quentin said, or use [browser file api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API)